# Meaning of maxUniformBufferRange in Vulkan

Tags: 3d, nvidia, vulkan

I am currently experimenting with Vulkan. One thing I did was rendering a Menger sponge (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_sponge) recursively.
Now one stage of the Menger sponge contains 20 sub-cubes. You can imagine that on stage 4 (stage 0 is just one cube) you'd end up with 20^4 cubes.
To display them at the correct position I ended up creating a lot of model matrices (one per cube) and writing them to a dynamic uniform buffer (Following the example over here: https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/tree/master/examples/dynamicuniformbuffer).
For stage 4 you'd have 20^4 cubes, meaning 160,000 model matrices with 64 Byte each = 10,240,000 Byte.
When trying to update the descriptor set for the dynamic uniform buffer I got some messages from the Vulkan validation layers:

```
Attempted write update to buffer descriptor failed due to: 
For buffer VkBuffer 0x22df6d00000000e8[] VkDescriptorBufferInfo range is VK_WHOLE_SIZE 
but effective range (10240000) is greater than this device's maxUniformBufferRange (65536).

The Vulkan spec states: If descriptorType is VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER 
or VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_DYNAMIC, the range member of each element of pBufferInfo, 
or the effective range if range is VK_WHOLE_SIZE, must be less than or equal to
VkPhysicalDeviceLimits::maxUniformBufferRange
(https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkWriteDescriptorSet-descriptorType-00332)
```

Copying over the whole buffer also lead to similar messages stating that I could not write more than  maxUniformBufferRange (65536 Byte) at once. So I figured I would just copy my matrices in batches of 65536 byte which worked and I got rid of those messages from the validation layers. Nevertheless the message above regarding the update of the descriptor set did not vanish.

Long story short: Even if there are messages the Menger sponge is displayed perfectly fine! So all of the matrices must have been properly transferred to the GPU (RTX 3080 (Mobile)). I even tried to run the rendering on my notebooks integrated GPU which reported a maxUniformBufferRange of 4294967295 Bytes. So I was wondering why my "high-end" GPU would not allow me to use more memory for my dynamic uniform buffer than the integrated GPU. Or maybe why it would say that it does not allow it and then it works perfectly fine? Is it just the validation layers reporting the wrong thing maybe?

Either way, I am still a newbie with Vulkan and Computergraphics so perhaps I am approaching the problem in the wrong way. Is there a way to render a lot of objects in different positions, scales and rotations while not using dynamic uniform buffers?

Comment: Why are you using a UBO for data that's too big for a UBO to handle?

Comment: "*Is there a way to render a lot of objects in different positions, scales and rotations while not using dynamic uniform buffers?*" What's wrong with dynamic uniform buffers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I was wondering why my "high-end" GPU would not allow me to use more memory for my dynamic uniform buffer than the integrated GPU.

Because the size of UBOs is not what makes your "'high-end' GPU" "high-end". It's the number of shader cores and the like.

Vulkan's limitations are not suggestions. You have to pay attention to them if you want to use it. And for UBOs, the minimum required limit on their sizes is only 16KB. So if your use case naturally needs to access more data than that, you need to either check the hardware to see if it supports a big enough limit or use a read-only SSBO (which is the better choice, since it works on all hardware).

As to why your case happened to "work", undefined behavior is undefined. Maybe you only accessed the available portion of the data, or maybe something else happened. But regardless, it isn't guaranteed to work, so it's still a bug in your code.

Comment: So I guess I will look into SSBOs! I was just curious why my integrated GPU would allow more than some random integrated chip. Thank you!